# Basic *nix Question (Mac OS X): Where is my path being set?

Tags: macos, unix, path, environment-variables

I have a path that starts like this

```
PATH=/opt/subversion:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin [etc]
```

and this is wrong (at least opt/subversion needs to be opt/subversion/bin). Where is this being set? I checked the usual suspects that I know:

```
.login
.profile
.bash
.bashrc
```

and it doesn't seem to be in any of these. Where do I need to look?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Stuff like this can be set on a per-user basis in which case you should be able to find something in your `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile` or `.profile` files. Or it can be set on a global level. In that case, I'd take a look inside `/etc/environment`, `/etc/profile` and `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

Comment: Thanks. That sounds like something I would've looked for and changed. And in fact there it is :) export PATH=/opt/subversion:$PATH right in /etc/profile.