# Changing the Ubuntu PATH doesn't work for me

Tags: ubuntu, path

I installed a few Ruby gems on a new install of Ubuntu 9.10, and after a few tries at running one, I realized that they failed because the PATH value did not contain their locations. SO I used the following command:

```
PATH=$PATH:/path/to/gem
export PATH
```

When I would echo the PATH, I would see my change in there. But when I opened a new tab on the console, or restarted it, my changes are gone.

I'm not sure what is the problem. Can anyone shed some light on it please?

Comment: the answer to this similar question should help: http://superuser.com/questions/73097/basic-nix-question-mac-os-x-where-is-my-path-being-set .. see also http://superuser.com/questions/112710/how-do-i-globalize-binaries-in-linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The commands you show alter the PATH for the command shell in which they are run.  When you open a new console tab or terminal window, you start a new shell.

In order to alter your PATH for every shell instance, you need to put those two lines in your ~/.bashrc file so that they get executed every time you start a new shell.

Answer (score 1):

> PATH=$PATH:/path/to/gem 
>   export PATH

That change environment only for child ptocess. Its good for testing.

For example

> xterm&

For permanent effect on current user, change in ~/.profile or ~/.bash_profile
For system global effect change /etc/profile